# Copy folder using dropbox shared link to a dropbox account without downloading and uploading again

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

User A shares a folder link. 
I want to use that shared link to copy that folder to my business dropbox account.
Catch is I don't want a method which downloads the folder to my server and uploads it to my dropbox account. I want a method by which I can pass that shared link as a parameter and make the api call and then dropbox copies the folder to my dropbox account at there end.
Is there a way using dropbox-api to copy directly to my dropbox account.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to add a folder from a Dropbox shared link directly to an account via the API, without downloading and re-uploading it. We'll consider this a feature request for a way to do so.